# How can I move or delete files created in certain time range?

Tags: linux, bash, find, stat

I'm making time lapse movies spanning several weeks and want to get rid of the pictures taken during the night (i.e. between 22:45 and 5:00 in this case), how can I do this easily?

I've found the following partial solutions:

- Using `find -newerXY` and specifically `-newermt` would be possible but requires me to loop over all dates as well,
- Using `stat` to query the mtime, but I don't know how to easily compare times in bash.

I'm now doing it manually, but I'm sure there must be a more elegant solution. Any ideas? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With `stat` (assumes all files in the same directory)

```
stat -c '%y %n' * | grep -E ' (22:4[5-9]|22:5|23:|0[0-4]:)' | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | xargs mv -t $dirForRemovedFiles
```

- this assumes that in the output of stat isn't depend on locale (it doesn't seem to be...), otherwise force the locale to "C".
- this assume that all the files are in the same DST segment.
- note the space between the quote and the parenthesis, this is what makes the regexp match only the beginning of the time stamp.
- for safety, the command above doesn't delete anything, it just moves the files to a directory where you'll issue a `rm *` once you have asserted that  you aren't missing anything.
- if you are paranoid, use `grep -E '^.{10} (22:4[5-9]|22:5|23:|0[0-4]:)'` to avoid false hits.

Comment: Warning: it may have worked for the OP but it should be noted that if there's a file with matching string (e.g. `foo 23:bar`) in its *filename* then it will be moved regardless of its mtime. Another issue: a matching file that has a newline in its filename won't be moved, I think.

Comment: Adjusting the regexp was left that as an exercise to the reader. If you have files with newlines in their names, you have a very sorry system and plenty of other problems to solve before wondering about this :)

Answer (score 1):

This semi-single line will print the "nightly" files:

```
( \
llimit=$((60*5+0)); \
ulimit=$((60*22+45)); \
find -type f -exec bash -c '\
hm=`stat -c "%y" "$0" | cut -c 12-16`; \
t=$((60*10#`echo $hm | cut -c 1-2`+10#`echo $hm | cut -c 4-5`)); \
test \( $t -lt $1 \) -o \( $t -gt $2 \)' \
{} $llimit $ulimit \; \
-print \
)
```

Sub-lines explained:

1. Starts a subshell to make variables local.
2. Calculates the lower limit in minutes past midnight.
3. Calculates the upper limit.
4. For every file a separate `bash` is executed; it will do the arithmetic.
5. Extracts mtime as `HH:MM`.
6. Converts `HH:MM` to a value as minutes past midnight.
7. Compares this value with precalculated limits.
8. These are arguments to the inner `bash`; inside, they are referred to as `$0`, `$1`, `$2`.
9. Prints the path iff the previous test returns true.
10. Ends the subshell.

Some remarks:

- `-exec` can act as a test in `find` invocation. This is hardly obvious, yet very powerful. In this case the test is true when the final part of the inner `bash` command line (i.e. `test`) returns true (i.e. its exit status is `0`).
- Bash arithmetic (`$((…))`) parses `01` or so as an octal number, `08` and `09` are invalid octal numbers. That's why we need to use `10#` to ensure that all numbers extracted from `stat` output are interpreted as decimal.
- I used `-lt` and `-gt` in `test`. Use `-le` and/or `-ge` if they suit you better.
- To remove files replace `-print` with `-delete` (or use them together: `-print -delete`).
- To move files to a single directory replace `-print` with `-print0` and build a pipe like this:

  ```
  ( … find … -print0 ) | xargs -0r mv -t /target/directory/
  ```