# How to search for files in Windows created within a time range on all dates?

Tags: windows-10, search

I need to search a folder for files created on all dates within a certain time range.

For example, a folder contains files created between 3/1/2016 02:00:00 to 3/3/2016 22:00:00, and I want the files created between times 06:00:00 to 10:00:00 on all three days.

Comment: [Similar question](https://superuser.com/q/1254652/432690).

Answer (score 0):

I can get you half way there, which is the date bit.

In the Quick Search box in Windows Explorer, enter

```
datecreated:
```

to get a date picker. Click a start date, then hold Shift and click an end date.

You can also pass in

```
ext:
```

to filter on a specific file extension e.g. ext:.txt